# magento category pages not shown in backend

Tags: magento, backend, categories, dashboard

I have a problem: on the Magento-Dashboard under "Catalog>manage Categories" is shown only the left colom with the already created categories, but I can't create new one or modify the existing ones. Take a look at the Picture and you will understand my problem

Below, the image of the page with the error: Catalog>manage Categories

[image]

Do you have any Idea where the problem comes from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I think that the problem come from a code-change, who has this sideeffect.